# How long does it take to break a stone block with an efficiency V (5) diamond pickaxe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft's enchantment system allows for adding special features to certain tools. The enchantment called Efficiency increases the rate at which blocks are mined. How long does it take to mine a stone block with an efficiency V (5) diamond pickaxe?

Answer (score 1):

With a Haste II beacon, it would be instant mining, so you would break one block per game tick. That's the 0.05 seconds in @Penguin's answer. However, without Haste II, after you break the first stone block in 0.05 seconds, you will have a 0.3 seconds delay before the next block starts breaking.

Source: [official wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breaking#Instant_breaking):

> When breaking a block, a tool and its enchantments do its speed value as "damage" to a block every game tick, and when that value equals or exceeds the block's hardness, the block breaks. If the tool and enchantments immediately equal or exceeds the hardness times 30, the block breaks with no delay; otherwise a 6 tick (3⁄10 second) delay occurs before the next block begins to break.
>
> For example, a player with Haste II holding an Efficiency V diamond pickaxe can break stone instantly, as the damage is (8+26)×(1+0.4)=47.6, which is greater than the base hardness of stone (1.5) times 30 (which is 45).

So, with an Efficiency V diamond pickaxe and nothing else, you would break the first stone block in 0.05 seconds, and the rest of them at a rate of one each 0.35 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, according to my math, which is probably wrong, it is **0.05 seconds**. Equation:

```
hardness = 1.5 (stone's hardness)
toolSpeed = 8 (diamond's toolspeed)
efficiencyLevel = 5 (level)
efficiencyBonus = efficiencyLevel ^ 2 + 1 = 26 (efficiency bonus speed)
----------------------------------------
Seconds: ceiling(1 / ((toolSpeed + efficiency bonus) / hardness)) / 20
-or-
Seconds: ceiling(1 / ((8 + (5 ^ 2 + 1)) / 1.5)) / 20
-or-
0.05
```

Equation info source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breaking#Speed

Comment: Unfortunately, without Haste II , this is wrong - the cap of 6 ticks is engaged, so it will be 0.3s.

Comment: @SF. ? Is the source wrong because I double checked the source and the only thing associated with haste does a quick `if` first; it won't execute if there is no haste meaning nothing changes. What would I add to the equation?

Comment: check the paragraph on Instant Breaking. It's phrased somewhat awkwardly, suggesting the delay is applied before next block - no, it's applied to breaking time of current block, as a speed cap. 0.05s is 1/20s so 1gt, that's instamine speed. You can't instamine stone without Haste II.

Comment: im talking about the code on the bottom not the paragraphs. try it according to the code

Comment: Less than a second. WOW!!!